# Specifying the location of multiple images

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I would like my added png files to merge with the video file - frame by frame. I need to specify the position of each image. I know I need to use -filter_complex for this, but I don't know how to do it.

I have this syntax:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i images/%03d.png -crf 16 -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

I kindly ask for help

Comment: what do you get with that syntax?

Comment: I get an output.mp4 file which is very similar to input.mp4 (difference in quality). But without added images

Comment: You'll need to use filters to combine the inputs in some way. See http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat

Comment: So you want to overlay each image, and each image needs its own position parameters?

Comment: @llogan yes, exactly

Comment: You can try the [sendcmd filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sendcmd_002c-asendcmd). See [Sendcmd in ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49600924/) for examples.